# If Linq Result Is Empty

Tags: c#, linq

If I have a linq query that looks like this, how can I check to see if there were no results found by the query?

```
var LinqResult = 
    from a in Db.Table
    where a.Value0 == "ninja"
    group a by a.Value1 into b
    select new { Table = b};

if(LinqResult.Count() == 0) //?
{

}
```

Comment: Why are you bothering to search for ninjas? Just assume that you can't find any. Ever.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

**You should try to avoid using the `Count()` method as a way to check whether a sequence is empty or not.** Phil Haack has [an excellent article on his blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/06/10/checking-for-empty-enumerations.aspx) where he discusses this antipattern.

[`Count()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038.aspx) must actually enumerate all elements of the sequence - which may be expensive if the sequence is based on multiple LINQ operations (or comes from a database).

You should use the [`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx) extension method instead - which only attempts to see if there is at least one element in the list, but will not enumerate the entire sequence.

```
if( !LinqResult.Any() )
{ 
   // your code
}
```

Personally, I also think that the use of [`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx) rather than [`Count()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038.aspx) better expresses your intent, and is easier to refactor or change reliably in the future.

By the way, if what you actually want is the first (or only) member of the sequence, you should use either the [`First()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356424.aspx) or [`Single()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357287.aspx) operators instead.

Comment: Despite the article's insight that `.Any()` only calls `.MoveNext()` once, ReSharper (7) will complain about possible multiple enumerations when using `.Any()` followed by other enumerating methods.  Maybe ReSharper is inaccurate or aiming for hyper-efficiency.

Comment: @CarlG: Not all sources of LINQ data are lazy, that's why `Any()` might be expensive.  (For example, on an `OrderBy` result, it won't save any time)

Answer (score 16):

```
if(!LinqResult.Any()) //?
{

}
```