# Porting LINQ expressions to Java

Tags: c#, java, linq

I'm porting a load of C# code to Java and keep having to deal with expressions like:

```
if (schedules.Where(s = > s.IsStillRelevantOn(calculatedDate)).Count() <= 0)
```

Is there an preferred way to do this or should I just loop through `schedules` (in this case) performing the necessary tests?

Comment: It says - Give me a list of schedules where the schedule is still relevant on the calculated date - Then it gets a count of how many get returned based on that criteria. Then it says if the count is less than or equal to zero the condition is true

Comment: http://abundantcode.com/best-java-equivalent-for-linq-c/

Comment: Are you allowed to use Java 8?

Comment: I'm developing my first Java app for Android which is version 7, I believe?

Comment: The C# code would be better written as `if (!schedules.Any(s => s.IsStillRelevantOn(calculatedDate))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that both the original code and the naive translation are not very efficient.  They both perform a count just to check if it's empty (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259895/if-linq-result-is-empty)).  In your example, you don't actually need the filtered list, so you can do something like:

```
bool hasElement = false;
for(int i = 0; !hasElement && i < schedules.size(); i++) {
    if(schedules[i].IsStillRelevantOn(calculatedDate))
        hasElement = true;
}

if (!hasElement) {
    // sequence is empty
}
```

Comment: You should break out of the loop if/when you find a match

Comment: That's what `!hasElement` does in the `for` predicate, though maybe an explicit `break` is more common.

Answer (score 0):

I can't compile this because I dont have your original code but it will be something like this

```
List<Schedule> matches = new ArrayList<Schedule>();

for(int x = 0; x < schedules.size(); x++){
   if(schedules[x].IsStillRelevantOn(calculatedDate))
       matches.add(schedules[x]);
}

if(matches.size() <= 0){
     //This is where you want your code

}
```

Comment: Yeah, this was going to be my approach but my question was really asking if there is a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: What do you mean by "elegant?"  This looks pretty "clean" to me.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, ideally this should really short circiut when it finds a match.  (The C# code doesn't, but it should too.)

Comment: @Servy what if he wants the entire collection?

Comment: @AMR That's not what his code does though.  It is impossible for the filtered items of the collection to be accessed from the code that he's porting.

Comment: @Servy ah yes I see what you're saying. Because the lynq happens within the conditional it isn't accessible outside of that conditional so it doesn't matter how many it has as long as its more than 0

Comment: I know that it was a quick snippet but List is an interface in Java, not a class.